# Optimize the function that generates data from large tick data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, cumsum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_[['Price', 'Volume', 'Open', 'High', 'Low']]
Out[16]: 
                               Price  Volume  Open   High    Low
datetime                                                        
2016-05-01 22:00:00.334338092  45.90      20  45.9    NaN    NaN
2016-05-01 22:00:00.335312958    NaN       1  45.9    NaN    NaN
2016-05-01 22:00:00.538377726  45.92       1  45.9  45.90  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590386619  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       3  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.591269949  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.591269949  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.591269949  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.707288056  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.719267600  45.92       2  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.719267600  45.91       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.731272008  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.731272008  45.91       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
2016-05-01 22:00:00.738358786  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.90
(..omitted rows)
```

From this dataframe, I defined a function that generates new dataframe:

```
res
Out[18]: 
                                High    Low  Open  Price  Volume
datetime                                                        
2016-05-01 22:00:00.334338092    NaN    NaN  45.9  45.90      20
2016-05-01 22:00:00.590493308    NaN    NaN  45.9  45.92      11
2016-05-01 22:00:00.731272008  45.92  45.90  45.9  45.91      10
2016-05-01 22:00:00.759276398  45.92  45.90  45.9  45.92      11
2016-05-01 22:00:00.927307727  45.92  45.90  45.9  45.90      36
2016-05-01 22:00:01.054379713  45.92  45.90  45.9  45.89      10
2016-05-01 22:00:01.251324161  45.92  45.89  45.9  45.92      10
2016-05-01 22:00:03.210540968  45.92  45.89  45.9  45.92      11
2016-05-01 22:00:04.450664460  45.92  45.89  45.9    NaN      10
2016-05-01 22:00:07.426789217  45.92  45.89  45.9  45.93      10
2016-05-01 22:00:10.394898254  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.93      10
2016-05-01 22:00:13.359080034  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.92      11
2016-05-01 22:00:17.434346718  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.92      17
2016-05-01 22:00:21.918598002  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.95      10
2016-05-01 22:00:28.587010136  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.94      10
2016-05-01 22:00:32.103168386  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.93      10
2016-05-01 22:01:04.451829835  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.94      14
2016-05-01 22:01:12.662589219  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.94      10
2016-05-01 22:01:17.823792647  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.94      10
2016-05-01 22:01:22.399158701  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.93      11
2016-05-01 22:01:23.511242124  45.96  45.89  45.9  45.92      10
(..omitted rows)
```

This function has two parameters: `df(dataframe)`, `n(size of Volume, for above, n=10)`.
From first date `date_1`, calculate the cumulative sum of volume, then if cumulative sum of volume is **greater or equal to n**, that moment is `date_2`. So, this block from `date_1` to `date_2` is aggregated to one row like this:

```
datetime : date_2

Price : price at date_2

Volume : sum of volume from date_1 to date_2

Open : price at date_1

High : max of high from date_1 to date_2

Low : min of low from date-1 to date_2

Do this to end of dataframe.
```

My problem is that my input dataframe has 60000000 rows. To aggregate data like above, it takes too much time. I want to optimize my code for function. Here is my code:

```
def tick_to_volume(df, n):
    flag = True
    np_df = np.array(df) #convert to numpy array
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    total_index = 0
    cum_n = 0
    cum_sum = np_df[total_index:,1].cumsum() #cumulative sum of volume
    while(flag):
        cum_n += n
        ix = (cum_sum[total_index:]>=cum_n).argmax() #index when cumulative sum of volume is greater or equal to n
        total_index += ix

        if (ix==0) and (np_df[total_index,4] < n): #for case that all cumulative sum of volume is less than n 
            return res

        cum_n = cum_sum[total_index]                       
        np_df_to_agg = np_df[total_index-ix:(total_index+1), :] #data to be aggregated

        data = {'datetime' : df.index[total_index],
                'Open' : np_df_to_agg[0,2],
                'High' : max(np_df_to_agg[:,3]),
                'Low': min(np_df_to_agg[:,4]),
                'Price' : np_df_to_agg[-1,0],
                'Volume' : sum(np_df_to_agg[:,1])}

        df_to_append = pd.DataFrame([data])
        df_to_append.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
        res = pd.concat([res, df_to_append])
        total_index += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partially vectorized approach. The idea is to split the problem into two parts.

1. Determine indices where each group starts and ends.
2. Perform `groupby` + `agg` using your custom logic.

The second part is easy. The first part can be accomplished efficiently with a bit of work + `numba`.

We iterate along `df.Volume` keeping track of the cumulative sum `x`. Every time `x` exceeds `n`, we mark the row for future use and set `x = 0`. After this, we have a series of indicators showing where each group ends. With a little massaging and taking care of the first/last group, we can turn `df.Break` into a series of IDs and proceed to the next step.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

n = 10


@njit(fastmath=True)
def find_breaks(vols, breaks):
    N = len(vols)
    acc = 0
    for i in range(N):
        acc += vols[i]
        if acc >= n:
            acc = 0
        breaks[i] = acc
    return


# create a blank column to store group ids
df["Break"] = np.nan
# mark points where volumes spill over a threshold
find_breaks(df.Volume.values, df.Break.values)
# populate the ids implied by thresholds
df["Break"] = (df.Break == 0).astype(np.float).replace(0, np.nan).cumsum().bfill()
# handle the last group
df["Break"] = df.Break.fillna(df.Break.max() + 1)

# define an aggregator
aggregator = {
    "Date": "last",
    "Price": "last",
    "Volume": "sum",
    "Open": "first",
    "High": "max",
    "Low": "min",
}

res = df.groupby("Break").agg(aggregator)

# Date  Price  Volume  Open   High   Low
# Break
# 1.0    22:00:00.334338092  45.90      20  45.9    NaN   NaN
# 2.0    22:00:00.590493308  45.92      11  45.9  45.92  45.9
# 3.0    22:00:00.731272008  45.91      10  45.9  45.92  45.9
# 4.0    22:00:00.738358786  45.92       1  45.9  45.92  45.9
```

Comment: WOW.... I'm so shocked... how fast it is... your code is so simple and so much optimized... Thank you. Respect you.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated `append()` has disastrous performance in Pandas and NumPy.  So instead of this:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    df_to_append.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
    res = pd.concat([res, df_to_append])
```

Do this:

```
res = []
while True:
    res.append(df_to_append)
res = pd.concat(res)
res.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

You can also simplify things by storing `data` as a tuple instead of a dict.  The keys are the same every time, and if you just ignore them, you can populate `res` as a list of tuples in the loop, avoiding the construction of many temporary DataFrames and key lookups later on.